# Different duration type output based on build type (release vs debug)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm using [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) in a statically linked Windows app. When I use the following code I get different values displayed in my dialog box based on whether I'm building in debug or release mode. Is there anything obvious I'm doing incorrectly here? Is this just something I need to live with?

```
    auto& CurrentTestDuration = m_pOperatingSLD->GetCurrentDuration();
    if (duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(CurrentTestDuration).count() >= SysLatOpt.m_maxTestDuration) {
        ReInitThread();
    }
    auto& data = m_pOperatingSLD->GetData();
    double measurementsPerSecond = static_cast<double>(data.m_statistics.counter) / static_cast<double>(duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(CurrentTestDuration).count());
    string CurrentTestDurationString = format("%R:%OS", CurrentTestDuration);
    m_strStatus.Append(("Elapsed Time: " + CurrentTestDurationString).c_str());
```

Here's an abbreviated version of the class containing the `GetData()` and `GetCurrentDuration()` methods:

```
class CSysLatData
{
protected: 
    SYSLAT_DATA         m_sld;

    const system_clock::time_point  m_startTime = system_clock::now();
    system_clock::time_point        m_endTime;
    duration<int>                   m_testDuration; 

public:
    const SYSLAT_DATA&  GetData() {return m_sld;}
    const duration<int>&        GetCurrentDuration() { return duration_cast<duration<int>>(system_clock::now() - m_startTime); } 
}
```

Output in release mode:

[image: release]

Output in debug mode:

[image: debug]

Full program here: https://github.com/Skewjo/SysLat_Software

Comment: What does `GetCurrentDuration()` and `GetData()` return (what is there return type)?  If they don't return by reference, then you have UB as `CurrentTestDuration` and `data` would be dangling references.

Comment: Very likely that this is just a manifestation of undefined behavior. Presumably, there are multiple threads involved, a common source of undefined behavior in C++. Though, if you need help, post a [mcve].

Comment: `GetCurrentDuration` returns a dangling reference. (Returning a const reference does not affect a temporary's lifetime, if that's what you were hoping.)

Comment: You're returning a reference to a temporary. Change `GetCurrentDuration` to return by value.

Comment: I've edited the question, adding an abbreviated version of the class containing the 2 methods in question.

Comment: @molbdnilo, perfect, thank you. That fixed it.